# How To Prove Pappus's Hexagon Theorem using the triangle $\bigtriangleup{XYZ}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The problem says that if $A,B,C$ are three collinear points and $D,E,F$ also are three collinear points, and the intersections of the lines $\overline{AB},\overline{AF},\overline{BF}$ with the lines $\overline{DB},\overline{DC},\overline{EC}$ are the points $P,Q,R$ respectively, then this three points are also collinear. We have to prove this using the triangle $\bigtriangleup{XYZ}$ (but it doesn't make sense to me, please help).

[Pappus Theorem Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMZfP.png)

Comment: P.D. Sorry I didn't noticed that you have to click the attachment to see the image

Comment: What theorems did not learnt about triangles?

Comment: Menelaus is your friend. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem

Comment: Your AB has to AE?

Comment: You can use projection to show that this may be proved for parallel lines.

Comment: it could be useful this related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281512/prove-pascals-theorem-by-homogeneous-coordinates) about proving pascal theorem which is a generalization